# Why do people say "God" in English and not "Gosh"?

Tags: minhag, shemos-sacred-names, english

When people speak Hebrew, they say Hashem instead of Y-HVH, because saying His name is impossible/forbidden.  Additionally, [when writing, some people write G-d instead of God](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/83).  Why when speaking English aren't people careful to say Gosh?

Comment: I think you are drawing a false correlation between these three things...

Comment: −1 for reverting to a version with AFAICT wholly irrelevant tags, rendering the question less comprehensible.

Comment: @msh210 His rollback was 10 seconds after yours was approved. He didn't see it.

Comment: It applies to all these tags...

Comment: @DoubleAA, no, see ^^

Comment: @yoel - Explain what you are talking about.

Comment: @AdamMosheh correct me if I'm wrong but it seems like you're saying: we don't vocalize HaShem as it's written (although al pi Kaballah we *do* say it), and many don't write out fully the English word G-d, therefore maybe we should also not say the English word G-d.  What is the kesher between the issur of pronouncing YKVK and between not writing out any given name of HaShem in the first place? Aside from this, I will also say that many people do *not* say "G-d" in a casual context.  I also don't see the basis to replace it with "gosh" - as far as I know, this is a gentile practice.

Comment: @هه that's probably another question altogether...

Comment: related: http://english.stackexchange.com/q/68336/19365

Comment: Yoel and @msh210, I vote to close, as it is impossible to tell what is being asked. It seems as though he is asking why people say one thing instead of another (which itself is not really on topic as far as I can tell), but even if that were on topic, the answer that was chosen does not address the question.

Comment: @SethJ, see recent comments to Menachem's answer, and my (consequent) most recent edit.

Comment: @msh210, I read the comments. It seems Menachem and I interpreted the question similarly, though I still don't see how his answer relates.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Many people are careful not to say a translation of one of G-d's 7 holy names (see [here](http://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/904982/jewish/Chapter-Six.htm) for the Rambam's version of them).

G-d is a translation of either A-D-N-Y or Y-H-V-H, depending on who you ask.

This is why many people use the word Hashem ("The Name") in Hebrew, or Aibishter ("One Above") in Yiddish.

See [this article](http://www.jewishpressads.com/printArticle.cfm?contentid=18784), which says that R' Moshe Feinstein held that if one made a blessing using the Yiddish word G-t instead of the Hebrew name of G-d, he fulfilled his obligation, and posits that R' Moshe would say the same thing if the English G-d was used.

There should be more direct sources that speak about saying a translation of G-d's names, but I can't find them right now.

Comment: How does this address the question, "some people write G-d instead of God. Why not Gosh"?

Comment: @msh210: The question could be worded a lot more clear, but based on the title, it appears that "why not Gosh?" means, "If people are careful to write G-d, why, when talking, do people not say Gosh?" That is the question I answered.

Comment: Oh, that makes sense. The fact that the asker accepted your answer indicates you're likely right, too. I'll edit the question.

Comment: Your link is dead

Comment: @user6591: I wasn't able to find a working link. In general, if you think dead links and link rot are a problem that can affect the quality of this site, please check out: https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3816/why-not-automatically-archive-links-in-questions-and-answers -- consider commenting and upvoting.

Answer (score 4):

> The Shach ([Yoreh De'ah 179:11](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=9732&st=&pgnum=201)) ruled that "God" spelled in a foreign language does NOT have the status of a "shem" and thus may be erased, lehatkhila. For more information, you can read this article: http://www.shamash.org/lists/scj-faq/HTML/faq/11-03-01.html

Source: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/15351/3

Comment: http://www.formspring.me/r/do-you-ever-worry-that-the-things-we-say-on-the-internet-will-come-back-to-haunt-us/202807455669852580

Comment: Doesn't seem to answer the question, as then God would also be allowed.

Comment: @ShmuelBrin It is.