# Is there a problem with saying "Oh my God" or "Oh my Gosh"?

Tags: halacha, speech-talking

It seems to me that religious Jews do not say "Oh my God" so I'm asking if there is anything wrong with saying that?

I'd also like to know if there would be an issue to say "Oh my Gosh"?

Comment: https://www.jpost.com/Breaking-News/Ovadia-Yosef-Jews-may-not-say-Oh-My-God-or-Ya-Allah

Comment: Related: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/50930/

Comment: I'm not sure, but your part about gosh might be a duplicate of https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/16511/.

Comment: Related: see @MauriceMizrahi answer at https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/98395/using-the-name-allah/106038#106038

Comment: @rosends Rightful response by Oveida. Back then when I sat in the bus and teenagers and preadolescent children constantly used that "oh my " or "swear by" remark I cringed. Doesn't feel right to say that in mundane contexts (e.g. puberty talk).

Answer (score 1):

Rabbi Ovadia Yosef expanded on the Biblical commandment “Thou shalt not take God’s name in vain”  declaring that Jews may not do so in other languages as well.

This makes saying “Oh my God” or the Arabic “Ya Allah,” both popular Israeli slang terms, halachically forbidden.

He explained that the “the prohibition is against saying His name when it is not in the context of a blessing or a prayer. We prefer to be stringent and apply the prohibition to languages like English or Arabic.”
https://www.jpost.com/breaking-news/ovadia-yosef-jews-may-not-say-oh-my-god-or-ya-allah

Comment: I'd take what a secular new agency reports (as "breaking news") in the name of a prominent Rabbi with a pinch of salt.

Comment: A better source for Rabbi Ovadia Yosef's opinion on the matter would be "[Mentioning Hashem’s Name in a Foreign Language](http://halachayomit.co.il/en/ReadHalacha.aspx?HalachaID=1808)" (on the Halacha Yomit website). It should be noted that there it also says: " _We can also consider the opinion of **the Poskim who say that there is no prohibition to mention Hashem’s name in a foreign language**, for this is not the actual name of Hashem. Thus, even though Halachically speaking one **should try** to abstain from mentioning Hashem’s name even in foreign languages_ ..." (emphasis mine).

Comment: Thank you for the other link. Shall I put it instead.

Answer (score -1):

I think saying the words "Oh my G-d" can be seen as taking the L-rd's name in vain in certain circumstances and not in others. For example, when in prayer.

As for "Oh my Gosh" or “gosh almighty,” my rabbi says we Jews should refrain from saying them since these terms are speaking about the Christian Holy Ghost.

He also says that saying “bloody” comes from the blood of Jesus and “knock on wood” refers to the crucifixion cross. In other words, he says that Jews accept Christian notions without realizing it and should recognize that these sayings are not Jewish, they are Christian.

Comment: Source please? Your first paragraph is false, as you can use His Name in non-prayer contexts (ex. have you ever wished someone שלום?), nor is it so clear that using His Name in English even counts (cf. about [writing it](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/36675/)). Your second paragraph hinges on equating "gosh" with "the holy ghost," but you don't demonstrate that that's the case.

Comment: @DonielF My rabbi says that Jews should refrain from saying  “gosh almighty” since when they do they are speaking about the Christian Holy Ghost. I do not know where he got the source. I'll have to ask my rabbi. He also says that saying “bloody” comes from the blood of Jesus and “knock on wood” refers to the crucifixion cross. In other words, he says that Jews accept Christian notions without realizing it and should recognize that these sayings are not Jewish, they are Chrisitan. About the first paragraph, I think you are write.

Comment: Even “my Rabbi says” is more information which is valuable to your post; would you please [edit] your answer to include that?

Comment: @DonielF Ok. I will do that.

Comment: Your rabbi's point about "bloody" has pretty good linguistic evidence that I have read elsewhere. It also applies to "gadzooks", funnily enough. What I don't see is why "gosh" invokes the Christian idea of Holy Ghost any more than it does the general monotheistic idea of God.

Comment: @Shmuel, knocking on wood isn't actually associated with the tzeilem, it comes from when churches were sanctuary and one couldn't be prosecuted or arrested while in one, so knocking on their doors was considered a way to avoid bad luck (eg. be let in)

Comment: @Mike Thank you for your comment. Thanks for letting me know. As for "gosh," I agree. I suppose "gosh" could invoke G-d in general.

Comment: @NoachMiFrankfurt That's interesting. I did not know that. Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

There are two separate prohibitions pertaining to saying God's name in vain. The first is in the עשרת הדברות:
לֹא תִשָּׂא אֶת-שֵׁם-ה' אֱלֹהֶיךָ לַשָּׁוְא

The other is an איסור עשה (positive prohibition), though I cant remember what it is at the moment. (Possibly כִּי שֵׁם ה' אֶקְרָא הָבוּ גֹדֶל לֵאלֹהֵינוּ).

The former applies only to saying God's name in vain in the context of a wasted or false blessing or swear. The latter applies to any other case.
It is implied by the Gemara and explicitly stated by some acharonim that the prohibition on saying God's name in another language only applies to when one is swearing or saying a blessing in another language. This is because when you do those things in another language, you're still invoking the idea of God into your statements. However, just mentioning the word God isn't actually his name, so it's meaningless without context.

Comment: Please substantiate that not taking God's name in vain has to do with the situation described. As far as I know the Rambam, and Shulchan Arukh only apply it to certain of God's name, and only in Hebrew.