# How would Judaism treat an instance of the Divine Name printed in Sutton SignWriting?

Tags: shemos-sacred-names

Names can be translated, though they do tend to be [somewhat transformed in the process](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/q/5161/177), the more so when translated into a signed language. Is a translated name treated with the same reverence as the original?

Signed languages can be written, most commonly with [Sutton SignWriting](http://www.signwriting.org/), though other schemes (Stokoe Notation, Ham-No-Sys, and si5s) also exist.

If a printed document contained a representation of the name of God, should it be treated with reverence and disposed of with care, or does the translation into a different language medium mean that it no longer counts as a form of the Divine Name?

Comment: related http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/23377/759 http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/36675/759 I think there might be a dupe in there, though this is well written +1

Comment: Your question seems to be about written representations of translations of divine names, whether that translation is to a signed language or a spoken one, yet your title is more specific. Can you [edit] your title to match your question or your question to clarify your intent?